# ActiveMQ - JDBC Master/Slave persistance issue with Mysql When configured in Cluster / Replicated.

Tags: activemq-classic

I was able to configure [ActiveMQ Cluster JDBC Master/Slave  here](http://activemq.apache.org/jdbc-master-slave.html) with the help of [link](https://dzone.com/articles/activemq-jdbc-master-slave). But, When I configure Mysql DB in a cluster then I'm getting the following message in my logs in both the machines(through various blogs I understand the setup is not completed properly).

> 2016-04-20 09:47:21,200 | INFO  | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@7c16905e: startup date [Wed Apr 20 09:47:21 UTC 2016]; root of context hierarchy | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | main
>   2016-04-20 09:47:22,821 | INFO  | Using Persistence Adapter: JDBCPersistenceAdapter(org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@1ed4ae0f) | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
>   2016-04-20 09:47:23,363 | INFO  | Database adapter driver override recognized for : [mysql-ab_jdbc_driver] - adapter: class org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.adapter.MySqlJDBCAdapter | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter | main
>   2016-04-20 09:47:24,015 | INFO  | Database lock driver override not found for : [mysql-ab_jdbc_driver].  Will use default implementation. | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter | main
>   2016-04-20 09:47:24,020 | INFO  | Attempting to acquire the exclusive lock to become the Master broker | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.DefaultDatabaseLocker | main
>   2016-04-20 09:47:24,053 | INFO  | Failed to acquire lock.  Sleeping for 10000 milli(s) before trying again... | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.DefaultDatabaseLocker | main
>   2016-04-20 09:47:34,065 | INFO  | Failed to acquire lock.  Sleeping for 10000 milli(s) before trying again... | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.DefaultDatabaseLocker | main
>   2016-04-20 09:47:44,078 | INFO  | Failed to acquire lock.  Sleeping for 10000 milli(s) before trying again... | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.DefaultDatabaseLocker | main
>   2016-04-20 09:47:54,089 | INFO  | Failed to acquire lock.  Sleeping for 10000 milli(s) before trying again... | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.DefaultDatabaseLocker | main
>   2016-04-20 09:48:04,102 | INFO  | Failed to acquire lock.  Sleeping for 10000 milli(s) before trying again... | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.DefaultDatabaseLocker | main
>   2016-04-20 09:48:14,115 | INFO  | Failed to acquire lock.  Sleeping for 10000 milli(s) before trying again... | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.DefaultDatabaseLocker | main
>   2016-04-20 09:48:24,128 | INFO  | Failed to acquire lock.  Sleeping for 10000 milli(s) before trying again... | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.DefaultDatabaseLocker | main
>   2016-04-20 09:48:34,140 | INFO  | Failed to acquire lock.  Sleeping for 10000 milli(s) before trying again... | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.DefaultDatabaseLocker | main
>   2016-04-20 09:48:44,154 | INFO  | Failed to acquire lock.  Sleeping for 10000 milli(s) before trying again... | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.DefaultDatabaseLocker | main
>   2016-04-20 09:48:54,166 | INFO  | Failed to acquire lock.  Sleeping for 10000 milli(s) before trying again... | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.DefaultDatabaseLocker | main
>   2016-04-20 09:49:04,176 | INFO  | Failed to acquire lock.  Sleeping for 10000 milli(s) before trying again... | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.DefaultDatabaseLocker | main
>   2016-04-20 09:49:14,188 | INFO  | Failed to acquire lock.  Sleeping for 10000 milli(s) before trying again... | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.DefaultDatabaseLocker | main
>   2016-04-20 09:49:24,200 | INFO  | Failed to acquire lock.  Sleeping for 10000 milli(s) before trying again... | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.DefaultDatabaseLocker | main
>   2016-04-20 09:49:34,213 | INFO  | Failed to acquire lock.  Sleeping for 10000 milli(s) before trying again... | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.DefaultDatabaseLocker | main
>   2016-04-20 09:49:44,227 | INFO  | Failed to acquire lock.  Sleeping for 10000 milli(s) before trying again... | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.DefaultDatabaseLocker | main

I'm not seeing anything other than this in my logs. I'm I doing something wrong over here? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The log said that the ActiveMQ server cannot grabs exclusive lock to become master. So it would retry after 10000 ms.
It means current ActiveMQ Server is in 'Slave' state, while the other is 'Master'.
More information about ActiveMQ lock:
http://activemq.apache.org/pluggable-storage-lockers.html